# Can i configure a subset of my cluster only for reduce purpose

Tags: hadoop, configure, mapper

Can i configure a subset of my cluster only for reduce purpose.That is  because i need to run mapper in some machines and ruducer in rest of the machines. Is it possible? How to do it?

Comment: Not without coding your own scheduler. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: To enable iteration in hadoop. Mappers retain the same data in all the iterations and reducer's output  given as input to mappers.

Comment: Retain it where? If it's on HDFS then it doesn't matter which worker machine is running the mappers or reducers because they all see the same data.

Comment: All i need to do is  give the output of reducer to mapper as input for next iteration without writing the output to disk.

Comment: That's really going against the MapReduce architecture. If you want in-memory transfer of data from one job to the next you might look at using Spark instead.

Comment: Explanation of my project using K-means clustering

a) Initially i give data and centroids.
b)mapper calculates distance and outputs <centroid ,data>,Mappers retain data in main memory.It should not flush it.
c)Reducer calculates new centroid<centrioid,data,data,.........>,But it should not write it to disk.
d) For next iteration i give new centroids to mappers. So iteration continues until i get the same centroids in two iterations.


IS THERE ANY CONCEPTUAL MISTAKE?

Comment: Conceptually MapReduce is pretty terrible at iterative algorithms. I would recommend you look into Spark, which handles these types of algorithms much much more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you. BUT It's my final year project. I have to do it in hadoop. I am ready to do modification in code. Help me with this.